# Objective-C in Qt with Mavericks

Tags: c++, objective-c, macos, qt, osx-mavericks

I've been using Objective-C mixed with C++ in Qt without any issues; using .mm files where required.

After upgrading my build machine to Mavericks, I initially noticed that the framework headers were missing, so installed the XCode command line tools, which fixed the issue.

Now, I'm getting a problem compiling Objective-C files with errors complaining about code in the frameworks. For example: -

> System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Versions/C/Headers/NSUserNotification.h:16:44: error: missing ',' between enumerators
>       NSUserNotificationActivationTypeReplied NS_AVAILABLE(10_9, NA) = 3

And

> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/Headers/NSApplication.h:58:34: error: expected ';' after top level declarator
>   typedef NSInteger NSModalResponse NS_AVAILABLE_MAC(10_9);

I've upgraded to Qt 5.2.1, but the issues remain and it's coming from including standard framework headers; in this case: -

```
#import <NSUserNotification.h>
#import <NSApplication.h>
```

Can someone please explain what's changed in Mavericks and how I can fix these errors?

Comment: All the error messages are here: http://pastebin.com/HS7iTc3h

Comment: Ah, ok. That's here, thanks: http://pastebin.com/FsZQ2y4M

Comment: The minimal header and mm files are here: http://pastebin.com/7CwJfbez

Comment: You absolutely should not be adding any framework includes. You're importing your frameworks not according to [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49894/discussion-between-merlin069-and-kuba-ober)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're [supposed to include the frameworks as Framework/Header.h](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/macosx/conceptual/BPFrameworks/Tasks/IncludingFrameworks.html). It seems that you've added some unnecessary includes to your project file.

The following works for me:

```
#project.pro
TEMPLATE = app

LIBS += -framework AppKit -framework Foundation

OBJECTIVE_SOURCES = main.mm
```

```cpp
//main.mm
#import <Foundation/NSUserNotification.h>
#import <AppKit/NSApplication.h>
#include <QCoreApplication>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
   NSApplication * app = [NSApplication sharedApplication];
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's with Qt 5.2.1 clang 64 bit.

Comment: So, thanks to @KubaOber who discovered what I needed to do was: 
1) Remove the framework includes from .pro files and 2)Change all #import <foo.h> to #import <framework_name/foo.h> as per apple docs.