# Creating UI with Qt in Xcode

Tags: xcode, qt

I need to develop an application to interact with an FPGA through TCP in a Linux environment. Given that I'm mainly an OS X guy and have only had minimal exposure to Linux, I figure that writing in Qt, which I'm *slightly* familiar with, in OS X will be the easiest way to get the job done.

Anyways, I was pretty disappointed after getting set up with Qt Creator, given that I'm used to Xcode and Storyboards for iOS development. I'm sure that if I stuck with it I'd figure out my way around, but I don't plan on ever doing much Qt in the future; if I am making something that needs to look pretty, I'd rather do it natively.

Long story short, is there any way that I can use Xcode/Storyboards to create my application's UI? Or any alternative to Qt Creator that would better suit someone who's most comfortable with Obj-C/Cocoa?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two options in Qt for designing UI

1. Programmatically, using the Qt class Widgets
2. Use Qt Creator's designer

I don't believe there is any current method to create the UI with Xcode and Storyboards. You could just use Qt Creator to design the UI, then import it into your XCode project, but learning Qt Creator and using it for what it does best is probably going to be easier for you in the long term.

Note that you can [use Objective-C with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22456384/objective-c-in-qt-with-mavericks), in Qt Creator.

Comment: If I design the UI in Qt Creator, are there any advantages in staying in Qt Creator to develop what needs to be done programmatically?

Comment: Objective-C in Qt? That would be awesome. Would there be any problems running the application in Linux if I wrote in Obj-C? Pardon my naiveness, just don't know how Qt deployment works

Comment: It will be quicker to make changes to the UI. You can also use the editor to setup signals/slots and actions too. Just think of Qt Creator as a different tool and don't expect it to work the same as XCode. Of-course, using Objective-C with Qt is for OS X and won't work for Linux so easily. If that's what you want, this may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11437361/how-to-objective-c-in-linux